# Plotting Points in Mathematica not Showing up

Tags: 3d, wolfram-mathematica, graphing

I am just trying to plot {3, 4, -2} and {7, -1, 5}. I am using ListPlot3D. All I get is the cube defined by the axis. I am not seeing my points at all. Dose anyone have any idea?

Here's what I enter:

```
ListPlot3D[{{3, 4, -2}, {7, -1, 5}}]
```

And I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are actually trying to plot individual points then

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{3, 4, -2}, {7, -1, 5}}, PlotStyle->PointSize[0.03]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Help for `ListPlot3D` says that it's purpose is to generate a surface from a list of point values and heights.  Two points are not enough to define a surface, but three points are.  For example:

```
ListPlot3D[{{3, 4, -2}, {5, 5, 5}, {7, -1, 5}}]
```

Gives:

[image: ListPlot3D]